# jQuery mobile back button disappear on autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, mobile, jquery-mobile, back-button

I'm actually working with jQuery mobile 1.0 and the auto complete widget from jQuery UI.
Everything works perfectly except one little thing :

When the user has been redirected (location.href) using the autocomplete feature, there is no back button on the page where he has been redirected.

I've set the *$.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn* to true in the *mobileinit* and the script is loaded before jQuery Mobile.

I didn't find any answer anywhere so this is why i'm asking to you guys

Thanks in advance

By the way sorry for the bad english it's not my first laguage

Answer (score 0):

How do you redirect the user to other page? With location.href? Then that's your problem, setting location.href causes a page refresh and then jQuery Mobile loses it's history (so it won't show the back button)

Please use `$.mobile.changePage( url )` to switch to another page

Something like:

```
        $("#yourAutocompleteID").autocomplete({
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $.mobile.changePage("nextpage.html?id="+ui.item.id);
            }
        });
```

For simplicity I pass here the data in the querystring